# Shattering image using canvas

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to shatter image to pieces using canvas , this is my code :

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'koals.jpg';
image.onload = cutImageUp;

 var imagePieces = [];
function cutImageUp() {

    for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 50+"px";
            canvas.height = 50+"px";
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(image, x *50, y * 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 50, 50);

           imagePieces.push(canvas.toDataURL());
        }
    }


    var anImageElement = document.getElementById('img');
    anImageElement.src = imagePieces[0];
}
```

the problem is that image is returning "blank image" (a.k.a its not loaded);
Console ain't throwing any error.
I'm opening it as local html file , both image and html document are in the same folder so there shouldn't be problem with toDataURL() not returning data due to image being on another domain.

Comment: Sometimes browsers treat local files specially for security purposes,  even if they're only interacting with other local files. You might find different results if you set up a web server so the script can be served from a normal URL.

Comment: Your problem is with the `50+'px'`for canvas width and height, remove the `+'px'`part and your good

Comment: without "px" it throws toDataURL error = Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.ggggg.html:25 cutImageUp

Comment: Then you've got a [Cross-origin resource sharing(CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem, when you access an image from a different domain, it will [taint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) your canvas. The solutions here are either to store your image on the same domain, convert your image to base64 (what I've done in the fiddle), or set credentials from server to accept CORS ([some reading about this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the `50+"px"` for canvas width and height, remove the `+"px"` part and your good.

From [w3Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/the-canvas-element.html):

> The canvas element has two attributes to control the size of the coordinate space: width and height. These attributes, when specified, must have values that are [valid non-negative integers](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/infrastructure.html#valid-non-negative-integer).

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'koals.jpg';
image.onload = cutImageUp;

 var imagePieces = [];
function cutImageUp() {

    for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 50;
            canvas.height = 50;
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(image, x *50, y * 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 50, 50);

           imagePieces.push(canvas.toDataURL());
        }
    }


    var anImageElement = document.getElementById('img');
    anImageElement.src = imagePieces[0];
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hd3q9w0b/)