# HTML to run JS image transform function

Tags: javascript, html

cutImageUp is a js script that's already been discussed in SE, here [Shattering image using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440980/shattering-image-using-canvas). But I have a different question about using it. The html I try doesn't do anything. I'm sure that I've done a simple wrong, but I'm too much of a noob to see it.

The cutImageUp script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var image = new Image();
image.src = "letere.png"; image.onload = cutImageUp;
var imagePieces = [];

function cutImageUp() {

for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 50;
        canvas.height = 50;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(image, x *50, y * 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 50, 50);

       imagePieces.push(canvas.toDataURL());
    }
}

var anImageElement = document.getElementById('img');
anImageElement.src = imagePieces[0];
}
</script>
```

My html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="cutImageUp.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<img src="letere.png" onload="cutImageUp()" width="50" height="50">
</img>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the page, the image appears, without the function applied. I might as well run the page without js. BTW, the files are in the same folder, and I tried using Base64, no luck.

Comment: First, in the `cutImageUp.js` file remove the `<script type="text/javascript">` at the beginning and the `</script>` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the <script> tags around the JavaScript code in cutImageUp.js. You only need those when you embed JS code in an HTML file.

Comment: The script tags aren't in the js. Sorry for the typo. So it still didn't work.  If the original image is height: 250 width: 50, then each canvas is 1/5 of it.       In the JS file, image draws each canvas. In the HTML, the image is the original image. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I used CSS sprites to do what I needed. I'd still like to perform this w/JS.